# How can I customize my webpack with create react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I want to customize the webpack devServer config in my app created with create-react-app to the following:

```
devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true, 
  }
```

I tried to just add it to my start script like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start --devServer.disableHostCheck=true",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

However this does not seem to work. What is the easiest way to get this done?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I honestly think any further customization will lead to you ejecting Create react app

Comment: If you are familiar with babel & webpack I suggest you to eject the CRA. It will expose all base the configurations (webpack, babel, devserver) including all the basic scripts needed to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you actually can override the config, (although I don't know how deep this goes).
You can use an npm package called Create React App Configuration Override(CRACO)

Read more about it in action [here](https://dev.to/kildareflare/how-to-modify-config-of-create-react-app-without-ejecting-5cbn#:%7E:text=The%20first%20step%20was%20easy,of%20CRA%20without%20ejecting%20it.&text=Turns%20out%20you%20can%20by,quick%20modification%20of%20the%20package.)

Ensure not to do this immediately in your production app, but rather spin up a test project to try this out.